# How to make a text field into input field when a button/icon is clicked in Angular/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 6, I want to change the text field into the input field when a button/icon is clicked. Part of Code and expected output is provided below. Thanks in Advance.

```
<div>
   <mat-form-field appearance ="outline">
       <mat-label>Given Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Given name" name="givenName" formControlName="givenName">
       <mat-icon matSuffix">create</mat-icon> #create - pencil icon
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[image]

When the edit button is clicked, it should show the input field similar to the next image.

[image]After changing the content (eg: new york to boston) it should show text field similar to the next image.

[image]

Comment: create two div with ngif condition on click first one is false and second one is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to display or hide the edit/submit button

HTML Code:

```
<h3>Edit form</h3>
<div>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="isEditEnable">
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter name" [(ngModel)]="name">
  </mat-form-field>
  <span *ngIf="!isEditEnable">Name : {{name}}</span>
</div>
<div class="example-button-row">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="!isEditEnable" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button>
  <button *ngIf="isEditEnable" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">Submit</button> 
</div>
```

In TS Code:

```
isEditEnable : boolean = true; // to show and hide the edit button

name : any;

onEdit(){
    this.isEditEnable =!this.isEditEnable;
}
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjcwvu)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div *ngIf="show; else elseBlock">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Given Name</mat-label>

    <mat-icon matSuffix>create</mat-icon> #create - pencil icon
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock> <input matInput placeholder="Given name " name="givenName " formControlName="givenName ">
  <mat-icon matSuffix ">Save</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon matSuffix ">Cancel</mat-icon>
</ng-template>
```

you can change variable `show` to false on `mat-icon matSuffix` click.

Comment: <button (click)="show = !show">{{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</button>

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a boolean variable to control the content. depending on how you created your formcontrol or form group:

```
<div *ngIf="show">
{{formGroupVar.controls['givenName'].value}} 
<button (click)="show !=show">
</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!show"> ...rest of your code </div>
```

this is simplest way to do it. but the logic is the same.